Jest Error: Cannot Use Import Statement Outside a Module in React&TypeScript Project
I have issues when running jest in my React&TypeScript project. Example of errors i'm facing:
SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

  1 | import styles from "./Similar_channels__slider.module.scss";
> 2 | import { Swiper, SwiperSlide } from "swiper/react";
    | ^
  3 | import { Navigation } from "swiper/modules";
  4 | import { Similar_channels__item } from "@/entities";
  5 |

  at Runtime.createScriptFromCode (node_modules/jest-runtime/build/index.js:1505:14)
  at Object.require (src/entities/ProfilePage__entities/Similar_channels__entities/Similar_channels__slider/ui/Similar_channels__slider.tsx:2:1)
  at Object.require (src/entities/index.ts:17:1)
  at Object.require (src/widgets/MainPage__widgets/Buy_placement/ui/Buy_placement.tsx:1:1)
  at Object.require (src/widgets/index.ts:9:1)
  at Object.require (src/pages/ProfilePage/ui/ProfilePage.tsx:1:1)
  at Object.require (src/pages/index.ts:1:1)
  at Object.require (src/app/layouts/ui/BaseLayout.tsx:1:1)
  at Object.require (src/shared/utils/renderWithRouter.tsx:2:1)
  at Object.require (src/widgets/Header/ui/Header.test.tsx:5:1)`

Also, i usually have the similar errors with SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'.
Swiper-react is used in the project, but i run test with component which don't use this library. I was trying to change transformIgnorePatterns, but it now worked. I use Windows.
jest.config.ts:
import type { Config } from "jest";

const config: Config = {
  transformIgnorePatterns: [
    "[/\\\\]node_modules[/\\\\](?!swiper[/\\\\]|my-other-dep[/\\\\])",
  ],
  testEnvironment: "jsdom",
  clearMocks: true,
  collectCoverage: true,
  coverageDirectory: "coverage",
  moduleNameMapper: {
    "^.+\\.(css|scss)$": "<rootDir>/styleMock.js",
    "^@/(.*)$": "<rootDir>/src/$1",
  },
  moduleFileExtensions: [
    "js",
    "mjs",
    "cjs",
    "jsx",
    "ts",
    "tsx",
    "json",
    "node",
  ],
}

babel.config.json:
{
  "presets": [
    ["@babel/preset-env"],
    "@babel/preset-typescript",
    ["@babel/preset-react", { "runtime": "automatic" }]
  ],
  "plugins": ["@babel/plugin-transform-modules-commonjs"],
  "env": {
    "test": {
      "plugins": ["@babel/plugin-transform-modules-commonjs"]
    }
  }
}

tsconfig.json:
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "baseUrl": "./src",
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["./*"]
    },
    "target": "ES2020",
    "useDefineForClassFields": true,
    "lib": ["ES2020", "DOM", "DOM.Iterable"],
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    /* Bundler mode */
    "allowImportingTsExtensions": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx",
    /* Linting */
    "strict": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true
  },
  "include": ["src", "typings.d.ts"],
  "references": [
    {
      "path": "./tsconfig.node.json"
    }
  ],
  "types": ["node", "jest", "@testing-library/jest-dom"]
}

